# Read More Link needs a small tweak

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set-up a 'Read More' function using the below code but I want the option for the user to close the expanded text after they are done. So a 'Read Less or 'Close' function.

I'm using the following code:

```
<script>
// DOM Ready
$(function() {

    var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

    $(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {

        // IE 7 doesn't even get this far. I didn't feel like dicking with it.

        totalHeight = 0

        $el = $(this);
        $p  = $el.parent();
        $up = $p.parent();
        $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

        // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
        $ps.each(function() {
            totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
        });

        $up
            .css({
            // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
            "height": $up.height(),
            "max-height": 9999
        })

            .animate({
            "height": totalHeight
        },500,function(){
            //Callback - after the animation is over
            jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();
        });

        // fade out read-more
        $p.fadeOut();

        // prevent jump-down
        return false;

    });

});
```

Here is a live example: http://www.cubadupa.co.nz/?post_type=marcato_artist

Any ideas? I'm new to javscript so sorry if this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could add and remove a class (I chose `.extended`).  Do the opposite of what was necessary to extend the element to shrink it.  I chose to 200px.  Adjust as needed.  I also adjusted your original click event to not be applied when the `.extended` class is included.

```
    var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

    // Click handler to extend a minimized element
    $(".sidebar-box").on("click", ".button:not(.extended)", function() {

        // IE 7 doesn't even get this far. I didn't feel like dicking with it.

        totalHeight = 0

        $el = $(this);
        $p  = $el.parent();
        $up = $p.parent();
        $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

        // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
        $ps.each(function() {
            totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
        });

        $up
            .css({
            // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
            "height": $up.height(),
            "max-height": 9999
        })

            .animate({
            "height": totalHeight
        },500,function(){
            //Callback - after the animation is over
            jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();
        });

        // Toggle extended class
        $p.toggleClass('extended');

        // update text
        $p.text('Read Less');

        // prevent jump-down
        return false;

    });

    // click handler for minimizing an extended button
    $(".sidebar-box").on("click", ".button.extended", function() {

            // IE 7 doesn't even get this far. I didn't feel like dicking with it.

            $el = $(this);
            $p  = $el.parent();
            $up = $p.parent();
            $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

            $up
                .css({
                // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
                "height": 200,
                "max-height": 200
            })

                .animate({
                "height": 200
            },500,function(){
                //Callback - after the animation is over
                jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();
            });



            // Toggle extended class
            $p.toggleClass('extended');

            // update text
            $p.text('Read More');

            // prevent jump-down
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: I appreciate you help. I have tried adding the code but it still isn't working. the 'Read Less' Text is showing but isn't clickable. See the example here - http://www.ninesixty.co.nz/cubadupa18/?post_type=marcato_artist

Comment: @JoshJ You might need to use event delegation, I will update the answer to reflect that